# jquery-datatables footer in a hidden div

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery-datatables (version 1.9) in a hidden div. It renders fine as long as I don't have a footer, but when I add a footer it is not displayed with proper widths. 
When I check width in HTML via firebug, I find all columns set to width 0.

I have already used fnAdjustColumnSizing on the table, but still same issue.

Here is my HTML table

```
<div id="Report" style="display: none">
    <table id="rpt" class="display">
        <thead>
        <tr style="background-color:#B9C9FE;color:#0033BB;">
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
        ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr style="background-color:#B9C9FE;color:#0033BB;">
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
        ...
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>       
    <br/>
</div>
```

Here is the datatable

```
var rptTable = $( "#rpt" ).dataTable({
    "bProcessing" : true,
    "bDestroy": true, 
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath" : "/js/DataTables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
        "aButtons": ["csv"]                                    
    },
    "sDom": '<"H"fp><tr><"F">T',                
    "aoColumns": [
            { "sWidth": "60px" },                                        
            { "sWidth": "100px" },                                        
            {    "sWidth": "65px" },                                  
            { "sClass": "right","sWidth": "65px"},      
            { "sClass": "right","sWidth": "65px"},       
            { "sClass": "right","sWidth": "65px" },     
            { "sClass": "right","sWidth": "65px" },    
            { "sClass": "right","sWidth": "65px"},       
            { "sClass": "right","sWidth": "65px"},       
            { "sClass": "right","sWidth": "65px"},     
            { "sClass": "right","sWidth": "65px" },       
            { "sWidth": "25px" }                                

    ],
    "bAutoWidth": false,   
    "sScrollX": "100%",
    "bSort": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "iDeferLoading": 0,
    "iDisplayLength": 25 
});
```

And here is the part of AJAX call that handles table data

```
success: function(returnData){
    var json = $.parseJSON(returnData); 
    rptTable.fnClearTable();
    if(json){
        if(json.Result === 'OK') {
            if(json.Records.length > 0){
                rptTable.fnAddData(json.Records);
                rptTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing(false);
                $( "#Report" ).show();
            }                                
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is the footer HTML as shown in firebug.

```
<div class="dataTables_scrollFootInner" style="width: 100px; padding-right: 0px;">
<table class="display dataTable" style="margin-left: 0px; width: 100px;">
<tfoot>
<tr style="background-color:#B9C9FE;color:#0033BB;">
<th class="ui-state-default" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px;">Col1</th>
<th class="ui-state-default" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px;">Col2</th>
...
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was a silly mistake of mine. I was using `fnAdjustColumnSizing` before trying `show` on hidden div. So I simply changed the following

```
if(json.Records.length > 0){
    rptTable.fnAddData(json.Records);
    rptTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing(false);
    $( "#Report" ).show();
}
```

to

```
if(json.Records.length > 0){
    rptTable.fnAddData(json.Records);
    $( "#Report" ).show();
    rptTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing(false);
}
```